# two-variable macro usage systemverilog

Tags: macros, system-verilog

I've searched the net but couldn't find answer to my problem. I'm trying to use two-variable macro in systemverilog.

In one file I declare the following macro:

```
`define TX_TOP_PATH(first_idx,second_idx)  aaa.F[first_idx].bbb.S[second_idx].ccc
```

In a second file (in a module), I try to use this macro withing generate nested for loops. for example:

```
wire if[15:0];
generate
    for (first_idx = 1; first_idx< 4; first_idx++)    
    begin : first_loop
       for (second_idx = 0; second_idx < 4; second_idx++)
       begin : second_loop
          assign if[4*first_idx + second_idx].clk = `TX_TOP_PATH(first_idx,second_idx).clk;
       end
    end
endgenerate
```

But when I do so, I get the error - CUVFGS: "Invalid for-generate index".

When I tried to put the macro definition in a parenthesis, like this:

```
`define TX_TOP_PATH(first_idx,second_idx)  (aaa.F[first_idx].bbb.S[second_idx].ccc)
```

I get the error - EXPSMC: "expecting a semicolon (';')"

Any ideas?

Liav

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems:

i) `if` is a reserved word. You can't call your `wire` `if`.

ii) You need to declare both `first_idx` and `second_idx` as `genvar`:

```
  wire iif[15:0];    // "if" is a reserved word

  generate
    genvar first_idx, second_idx;    // these need to be declared as genvars
    for (first_idx = 1; first_idx< 4; first_idx++)    
    begin : first_loop
       for (second_idx = 0; second_idx < 4; second_idx++)
       begin : second_loop
         assign iif[4*first_idx + second_idx] = `TX_TOP_PATH(first_idx,second_idx).clk;
       end
    end
  endgenerate
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/m_6

Comment: well, I wasn't accurate with my example. the wire name is not actually "if" but something like "dut_if", so this is not the problem. about the genvars, you're right, I'm actually use genvar for both indices, but I forgot to copy it here. and still not working :(

Comment: Then I think you need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is always a goood idea from the start.